Why are there general use extras/flaws that aren't listed in extras/flaws? (+a resource for those wanting to use them)
Something I noticed is that on pg. 149 where Afflictions are listed, the Effect Description format has the following to say about how Extras are listed "A listing of extras relevant or unique to the effect. Extras unique to an effect are in colored orange." This means, any extra (and probably flaws) that are listed with black text are general use extras that can be applied to all sorts of things. Why are there Extras/Flaws that do not have orange text that are not listed in Extras/Flaws, effectively hiding the fact that they're meant to be general use? Reading past this is optional, given the rest is just informing people of some of most of the black text extras that I've found so far.
For the sake of reference, I went out of my way to list (almost) all applicable extras/flaws that use black text and expand on what both GMs and players are capable RAW. If you don't care about Rules as Written you were probably doing some of these things anyways after having looked into the book long enough.

Some cool things you can do here that would be well known if listed properly:

Instant Powers with Concentration and Independent do not have a Sustained Duration, as maintaining a power is not the same terminology as sustaining it. This means you can get powers that are effectively sustained...with Triggered. Weird but alright.
RAW, you can give Teleport (Portal) the Independent Extra to make the Portal a free action to maintain. Worth exploring though I'm not sure what the coolest way of doing it RAW is yet.
Damaging can be applied like linked Damage without extras of its own, but rather inherits the extras of the power its applied to. Damaging Afflictions now only need to pay for Multiattack, Increased Range, and Reaction Extras once rather than twice. This is also interesting for powers like Nullify, Mind Reading, and Luck Control, which all start with either Ranged or Perception making the use of the Damaging Extra in this way more valuable.
Cumulative Damage seems crazy, though Cumulative Multiattack Afflictions were already devastating.
Movable Transforms and Summons to effectively tether them to you to be thrown around later when you want to is interesting. You could also potentially move Concealment Effects like how Darkness can be moved in D&D.
Sensory Link allows for Find Familiar powers without having to jury-rig Summon to Remote Sensing.
Broad and Simultaneous as well as 'Narrow' and the existence of Broad as a flaw seems to imply a tier system similar to Transform about how general powers can be and the amount of points per rank it takes for something to be all encompassing. However, Broad Simultaneous Enhanced Trait: Abilities seems nuts already, so until I find a more official ruling on the subject I'm not going to delve into it.
We don't talk about Metamorph that feels like a massive oversight.


I suspect that what you've happened upon is more about editing issues than any hidden rules. Concentration is just Increased Duration on an Instant effect, and is described on page 147. I suspect that Cumulative and Progressive were only meant to be applied to Affliction. Improvised Weapon and Throwing Mastery are simply the Advantages of the same name. Similarly, I suspect that Independent is only meant to apply to Illusion, the same way that Responsive got added to Summon in the Summoning Power Profiles.
As per some of our prior discussions, I suspect that Rule 0 probably covers you deciding that you want to extend some of these past where they're pretty clearly meant for one particular power. The GM is allowed to add whatever Extras and Flaws that they would like into their game.

Nullify's Sustained Extra does the same as Independent in book and does directly apply to Instant Effects that have Concentration. Cumulative/Progressive are black texted so regardless its still something you can do raw. Improvised Weapon/Throwing Mastery advantages specifically apply to the power, not throws in general, as opposed to Luck on Luck Control which just gives you the advantage. As for editing issues, Cumulative as concepts are listed on the same page as the general rule. You can say its a editing issue, but its difficult to say the rules say anything but what is explicitly told.

Overall this answer is a assumption. Rather than that, I'm looking for the answer with a source, since this is a big deal for RAW play in terms of what you can do without GM interference beyond the typical bans of metamorph and variable.
